# How to pass buffer address to c?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes

I want to pass the address of a numpy array buffer to c function,
My C function looks like:

```
void print_float_buff(void *buff)
{
    float *b = (float *)buff;
    printf("Float Data: %f, %f, %f,\n", b[0], b[1], b[2]);
}
```

In python my code is:

```
import numpy as np
fun=ctypes.CDLL("./mylib.so")
l = np.array([10., 12.6, 13.5], dtype = 'float')
address, flag = l.__array_interface__['data']
fun.print_float_buff(ctypes.c_void_p(address))
```

A am getting completely different data in my c function. Address doesn't seem good. How can I pass correct address to my C function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In c, float size is four bytes while in python float size is 8 bytes.
If I allocate array like this:

```
l = np.array([10., 12.6, 13.5], dtype = 'float32')
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `.argtypes` correctly, ctypes will tell you the type is wrong.  Below requires a one-dimensional array compatible with `c_float`:

test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API void print_float_buff(float *buff, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("buff[%zu] = %f\n",i,buff[i]);
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.print_float_buff.argtypes = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(c_float,ndim=1),c_size_t
dll.print_float_buff.restype = None

a = np.array([10., 12.6, 13.5])
dll.print_float_buff(a,len(a))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    dll.print_float_buff(a,len(a))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: array must have data type float32
```

Changing the array as suggested:

```py
a = np.array([10., 12.6, 13.5],dtypes='float32')
```

Output:

```
buff[0] = 10.000000
buff[1] = 12.600000
buff[2] = 13.500000
```